# Youtube Api Upload Request Blocked By Cors

Tags: javascript, google-api, youtube-api

I Have been using youtube Api V3 for more than 2 years it was working fine until yesterday once uploading videos return error (I haven't Changed anything)

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2Cstatus&uploadType=resumable' from origin '' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This is the code I'm using (And It was working Fine)

```
var MediaUploader = function (options) {
    var noop = function () { };
    this.file = options.file;
    this.contentType = options.contentType || this.file.type || 'application/octet-stream';
    this.metadata = options.metadata || {
        'title': this.file.name,
        'mimeType': this.contentType
    };
    this.token = options.token;
    this.onComplete = options.onComplete || noop;
    this.onProgress = options.onProgress || noop;
    this.onError = options.onError || noop;
    this.offset = options.offset || 0;
    this.chunkSize = options.chunkSize || 0;
    this.retryHandler = new RetryHandler();

    this.url = options.url;
    if (!this.url) {
        var params = options.params || {};
        params.uploadType = 'resumable';
        this.url = this.buildUrl_(options.fileId, params, options.baseUrl);
    }
    this.httpMethod = options.fileId ? 'PUT' : 'POST';
};
MediaUploader.prototype.upload = function () {
    var self = this;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open(this.httpMethod, this.url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Upload-Content-Length', this.file.size);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Upload-Content-Type', this.contentType);

    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        if (e.target.status < 400) {
            var location = e.target.getResponseHeader('Location');
            this.url = location;
            this.sendFile_();
        } else {
            this.onUploadError_(e);
        }
    }.bind(this);
    xhr.onerror = this.onUploadError_.bind(this);
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(this.metadata));
};

var uploader = new MediaUploader({
        baseUrl: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos',
        file: file,
        token: Token,
        metadata: metadata,
        params: params,
        onError: function (data) {
            //log error
        }.bind(this),
        onProgress: function (data) { 
        //Do progress
        }.bind(this),
        onComplete: function (data) {
             //on upload success
        }.bind(this)
    });

    uploader.upload();
```

Comment: Has anything changed in your application? Versions, etc.

Comment: no nothing changed